# how to reuse k8s validation in my own CRD controller

Tags: kubernetes, openapi, kubebuilder

I created an `CRD` like this:

```
import v1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"

type ApplicationSpec struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`

    PodSpec v1.PodSpec `json:"podSpec"`

    ...
}
```

notice that I reused `PodSpec` from core apigroup in my CRD

To avoid user apply invalid yaml files, I decided to add validation logic in my CRD controller, for simple fields like `Name`, it's easy to check it's correctness using regex, while for complex and native kind like `PodSpec`, since k8s already have validation logic for that, I feel the right way is reuse that in my controller, but how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can reuse the [upstream `ValidatePodSpec` directly](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/apis/core/validation/validation.go#L3189-L3264).

You would need to import a couple packages first:

```golang
import (
    "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/core/validation"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/validation/field"
)
```

Then make use of `ValidatePodSpec` in your controller method:

```golang
errs := validation.ValidatePodSpec(instance.podSpec, field.NewPath("podSpec"))
```

Comment: hi, how you managed to use pkgs under kubernetes? k8s seems discourage people consume it as lib by importing non-exist module version like this: `k8s.io/api v0.0.0` in its go mod (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/go.mod#L124)

Answer (score 0):

Also desire such a functionality to be provided as a library. There is a comment about using `go get` for `k8s.io/kubernetes` upstream.
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/80316#issuecomment-512991205
And the issue that is caused by using wrong configuration for PodTemplateSpec could be found here https://github.com/googleforgames/agones/issues/1298
Namely: we create a CRD successfully, however it become unhealthy later because pod could not be created.